# Linear algebra: What is the difference between target space of a function and the image of a function?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

I'm confused about the difference between target space of a function and image of a function. My textbook (Linear Algebra with Applications 5th edition Otto Bretscher) provided this information when introducing image, but I'm still struggling to understand conceptually the difference between target space and image. [Textbook definition of image in relation to target space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRqit.png)

Comment: The image is the subset of the target space that has all the elements of the target space that get mapped to

Comment: imagine you’re shooting something/playing darts or whatever. There’s the thing you aim at, and there’s the thing you actually hit. That’s the difference between target space and image.

Comment: Another word for a 'target space' is a codomain of the function. The domain is X and the codomain is Y. Yet the image is just the range of the function. For example, your function can carry all points in the domain into just one point in the codomain, and, so the image (range) would be just that one point in the codomain ('target' space).

Comment: Example: $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\quad f(n):=1$. The image of the function $f$ is the set $\{1\}$, which is subset of the target space $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo, can you explain this again, but with snowballs?

Answer (score 5):

Consider functions from the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ to the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. One such function is $F(x, y) = (2x, y/2)$, for example, sending $F(1, 1) = (2, 1/2)$. Another function is $G(x, y) = (0, 0)$, i.e. $G$ sends *every* input exactly to the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Both $F$ and $G$ have the same target space: $\mathbb{R}^2$. But the image of $G$ is just the single point $(0, 0)$. With a bit of work, you might show that the image of $F$ is actually also all of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.

A function $f \colon X \to Y$ maps values of $X$ to values of $Y$. The space $Y$ is what your textbook calls the target space, in the literature this is also known as codomain. Note that specifying the target space specifies the universe in which the values of the function "live". The image of the function is the set of values which the function attends. The target space must always contain the image, otherwise the function is not well defined.

To make this more intuitive, consider as $X$ the population of a specific country, and define a function $f$ which maps a person to their shoe size (It does not matter whether you choose American or European shoe sizes, or any other scale which is based on number; for the sake of uniqueness I will choose European shoe sizes here). This function will take values in the rational numbers, but there are no negative shoe sizes. Therefore a valid target space would be $\mathbb{Q}$, but also $\mathbb{R}$ would be a valid target space, because the image is contained in both of these spaces.

Answer (score 3):

Too long for a comment.

Though "range" did not come up here it does not help that this common term can be ambiguous.  If we have a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ one might say the range is $Y$ but it could mean either the image or target as described above! For example there is nothing wrong with defining $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=x^2$ even though it clearly goes into not onto $\mathbb{R}$.

What often happens at the high school level might be that one is asked for the range of something like $f(x)=x^2$ (it is usually NOT presented as a map with arrows) and the desired answer is $y\geq 0$ or something more formal with set brackets. In other words, "range" is taught to mean image.

In your case, "image" is clear (it is the values actually hit) and the more common term for "target" is codomain. And the picture in your link makes the intent very clear!

Answer (score 2):

In the books I've read, something is usually not very emphasized: is a map a **triple** $(X,Y,f)$ where $f \subset X\times Y$ satisfies some conditions, or is a map just a **set** $f$ **of couples**? Depending on the choice of definitions ("triple-maps" or "set-of-couples-maps"), the answer to your question may be different.

Regardless of the definition, the **range** of $f$ (on $X$) is the set $\{y \ \vert \ \exists x \in X,\quad f(x) = y\}$.

However, the **target space** of $(X,Y,f)$ is, by definition, $Y$, whereas $f$ alone has no target space *per se*; the target map is meaningful for "triple-maps" but not "set-of-couples-maps".

For example, with the triple definition the map $(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}, x\mapsto x^2)$ has range $\mathbb{R}_+$ and target space $\mathbb{R}$; the map $(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}_+, x\mapsto x^2)$ has range $\mathbb{R}_+$ and target space $\mathbb{R}_+$. These two "triple-maps" are different, but as "set-of-couples-maps", they are equal. In this example, they have different target spaces, but equal ranges.

EDIT: John Bollinger's comment is a nice way of summing up what I meant to say!

Comment: Among the important points brought out here is that target space / codomain is a *choice* made in defining the function, not a property derivable from (say) the set of couples view of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Target Space (Codomain):

The target space, also known as the codomain, is the set of all possible output values that a function can produce.
It represents the full space of potential results of a function, regardless of whether or not those values are actually reached.
When defining a function, you specify its target space to indicate where the output values should belong.
Image (Range or Coimage):

The image of a function, also called the range or coimage, is the actual set of values in the target space that the function can attain or "hits."
It consists of all the output values that the function can produce when you apply it to various inputs from its domain.
The image is a subset of the target space and represents the specific values that the function can output.
To illustrate the difference, consider a linear transformation (function) T: V → W, where V and W are vector spaces:

The target space (codomain) is the vector space W, which includes all possible vectors in that space.
The image (range) of the linear transformation T is the subset of W consisting of all vectors that can be obtained by applying T to vectors in V.
In summary, the target space is the entire space of potential outcomes, while the image is the actual set of outcomes achieved by the function. It's possible that a function may not reach all elements of its target space, in which case the image is a proper subset of the target space.

Comment: This is either an amazing off-the-cuff answer or, um, it might need a source, but +1 for: _In summary, the target space is the entire space of potential outcomes, while the image is the actual set of outcomes achieved by the function. It's possible that a function may not reach all elements of its target space, in which case the image is a proper subset of the target space._" That seems the crux from the OP's image.